# Type assertion missing properties

Tags: typescript

```
class Human {
  constructor() {}
  liveLife() {}
}

class Superhuman extends Human {
  saveWorld() {}
}

class PlayableCharacter {
  playable;
  constructor(playable: Human) {
    if (typeof playable === typeof Superhuman) {
      this.playable = playable as Superhuman;
    } else {
      this.playable = playable;
    }
  }
}

const character = new PlayableCharacter(new Superhuman());
```

then I begin accessing the superhuman properties

```
character.playable. // <-- cannot access saveWorld function
```

I can see the properties for the base human class but not for superhuman.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: `saveWorld()=>{}` is not valid syntax...

Comment: @vr. my mistake. Just fixed it for the example.

Comment: Did you mean `character.playable` instead of `character` when trying to access the saveWorld function

Comment: `this.playable = playable as Superhuman` doesn't actually change the type of the property. Even if you did access `new PlayableCharacter(new Superhuman()).playable`, it's a `Human`.

Comment: Presumably you wanted something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE8VZW), using generics.

Comment: @vr. you could also just use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) at that point.

Comment: @vr. and johnrsharpe thank you so much! I never knew how to do this. This is a life changer.

Answer (score 2):

Type assertions only assert that an expression is of some type. When you use

```
this.playable = playable as Superhuman;
```

you aren't "changing" the type of `playable`, you're just assigning a `Superhuman` to `this.playable`. Presumably, what you really want is a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), so that the type information given in the constructor is preserved:

```
class PlayableCharacter<Character extends Human> {
    playable: Character;

    constructor(playable: Character) {
        this.playable = playable;
    }
}
```

Now when you create a new playable character with a superhuman, TypeScript knows that the `playable`  property type is `Superhuman`:

```
// inferred as PlayableCharacter<Superhuman>
const character = new PlayableCharacter(new Superhuman());

character.playable.saveWorld(); // okay
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEASCuBbMA7aBvAUNH1gHsUIAXAJ3mGP1IAoBKDAX21xAEsA3AUwBk2AzLvSaZmmUJBgBleAAcupABZJU0LgA9iXFABMYCZGiy5oEMNwDq1EDuHpmYiVGgAFcAE8wAIxBcAwopgpGCUCgA8AUEhWqRqmtp6cCooAHwYLDiyHt6+AFzQkcGhpADcmBl4hCTklNQ0WWCePlz5hdEKDMYmuMSKbBAAdA1NvtAAvNDDOVxlJg7lBETEeIFFMePQKFwA7q7ZzW3FNFu7MvJKyfR0ZeKr7aRD+74DZpbWttdAA)